# Can I make startActivityForResult() not returning anything?

Tags: android

Like the title say, I am in a special situation that I may or may not return a value from startActivityForResult(). So if I don't return anything, is that ok?

Comment: I am fairly certain if you don't return anything you will eventually get a RESULT_CANCELLED return once onDestroy is called on the activity that you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its ok. You can just finish the activity without returning any result. In the onActivityResult, you will get the null intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need result from `Activity` then just call `startActivity()` instead of `startActivityForResult()`